# CSV2 dat file headers and columns manipulation

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV file which is transformed to .DAT. I have an AWK file which is supposing to do the mapping of the DAT file. The code from the AWK file is the one below.

The content of the DAT file looks like this (tab separated):

```
ODT AGE CDT CO SEX TIME VALUE COMMENT
P3 Y6-8 ACT FG F 2011 1297
P4 Y3-4 EMP FG M 2011 6940 b
P1 Y7-9 GRT FG F 2011 0 c
```

What I have to do is the following:

1. keep the headers together with the columns order - done
2. if the value for COMMENT is "c" then the column COMMENT must be changed to STRING_COM, if the value for COMMENT is "b" (or anything different than "c") the COMMENT column must be changed to STRING_STATUS
3. No matter what other columns will be received except the ones mentioned here they must be removed
4. VALUE column should be renamed in "NUMB"

Here is my code which fix only the 1st point

```
BEGIN {
  FS = "," ;
  OFS = " " ;
}

{
  if(NR == 1)
  {
    split($0, tmp, ",");
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    fields[tmp[i]] = i
    print tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4], tmp[5], tmp[6], tmp[7], tmp[8]

   else
   {
     split($0, tmp, ",");
     for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
     fields[tmp[i]] = i

    print tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4], tmp[5], tmp[6], tmp[7], tmp[8]
  }
}
```

Expected result in the dat file:

```
ODT AGE CDT CO SEX TIME NUMB STRING_COM STRING_STATUS
P3 Y6-8 ACT FG F 2011 1297
P4 Y3-4 ERT FG M 2011 6940 b
P1 Y7-9 GRT FG F 2011 0 c
```

in the CSV file the separator is "," but the dat file must be with tab separator that's why I have the code ....FS=","
regarding third point, the explanation is:
I might receive other columns which are not needed.
so in conclusion I have somehow to specify that only these columns are needed: ODT AGE CDT CO SEX TIME VALUE COMMENT)
any other columns received must be ignored

**The CSV file is:**

```
ODT,AGE,CDT,CO,SEX,TIME,VALUE,COMMENT
P3,Y6-8,ACT,FG,F,2011,1297,
P4,Y3-3,EMP,FG,M,2011,6940,b
P1,Y7-9,GRT,FG,F,2011,0,c
```

the solution provided below works fine.
still some issues:

if I put the column COMMENT after AGE or CDT the "c" character is added in a second line. the second line contain two tabs and then the "c" character. 
and if the COMMENT is at the end and contains character "c", "bcc" the result is putted only on STRING_STATUS instead of doing the separation > "c" goes to STRING_COM and "bcc" goes to STRING_STATUS

the following cases scenario must be implemented:

1. if the VALUE is ":" then NUMB is null
2. if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "c" then NUMB is null and STRING_COM is "c"
3. if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "u" then NUMB is null and STRING_STATUS is "u"
4. if the VALUE is "14,38" and COMMENT "d" then NUMB is "1438" and STRING(both) is null
5. if the VALUE is "14,38" and COMMENT "du" then NUMB is "1438" and STRING_STATUS is "u"
6. if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "cd" then NUMB is null and STRING_COM is "c"
7. if the VALUE is ":" and COMMENT "bc" then NUMB is null and STRING_COM is "c" and STRING_STATUS is "b"

### how can I do this?

is anyone who can help on this issue?

Comment: `3. No matter what other columns .... ` what does this mean?  also you said your dat file `Tab` sep. but your codes used `FS=","`?

Comment: i have answered inside the main post

Comment: Put some content from your `CSV` file which has some data where lines have extra columns. Are your required columns in particular order, like first 8 or something?

Comment: the number of columns is not always the same. the column order is random. what I know is that I need only the columns mentioned above.if we would have the order given by me here it would be perfect. if not we can skip this part

Comment: @user3560736 Looking at the data how will you identify which column data belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

If all rows have same column order:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  FS=","; OFS="\t";
  a["ODT"]=1;a["AGE"]=1;a["CDT"]=1;a["CO"]=1;
    a["SEX"]=1;a["TIME"]=1;a["VALUE"]=1;a["COMMENT"]=1;
}
NR==1 {
    $NF=substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1);
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a) a[$i]=i;
}
{   print $a["ODT"],$a["AGE"],$a["CDT"],$a["CO"],$a["SEX"],$a["TIME"],NR==1?"NUMB":$a["VALUE"],
    NR==1?"STRING_COM"OFS"STRING_STATUS":($a["COMMENT"]!="c"?""OFS$a["COMMENT"]:$a["COMMENT"]);
}' input.txt
```

I changed the input a bit, added one column(`ADDED`) and reordered two others(`TIME` and `VALUE`):

```
ODT,ADDED,AGE,CDT,CO,SEX,VALUE,TIME,COMMENT
P3,111,Y6-8,ACT,FG,F,1297,2011,
P4,222,Y3-3,EMP,FG,M,6940,2011,b
P1,333,Y7-9,GRT,FG,F,0,2011,c
```

Output:

```
ODT AGE CDT CO  SEX TIME    NUMB    STRING_COM  STRING_STATUS
P3  Y6-8    ACT FG  F   2011    1297        
P4  Y3-3    EMP FG  M   2011    6940        b
P1  Y7-9    GRT FG  F   2011    0   c
```

**EDIT**

If input has more column than needed, the extra columns will not appear in output, for example the input I have used here has an additional column `ADDED` that is not appeared in output.

It will print output in the order that is preferred in question i.e. `ODT AGE CDT CO SEX TIME NUMB STRING_COM STRING_STATUS` no matter in what order they appeared in the input. Again in the input I have used the column `VALUE` appeared earlier that `TIME` but in the output `TIME` is first and `NUMB` is second. By

> If all rows have same column order

I mean if all rows follow the order of the header line. If the order in header is `ODT AGE CDT CO SEX TIME VALUE COMMENT` the data in all rows appeared in this order if the order in header is `AGE ODT CDT CO SEX TIME VALUE COMMENT` then data in all other rows have this order. It doesn't assume that for example `ODT` is always the first column in all files, it assumes in a file the order is defined by the header. If it is not the case, the code won't work.

**EDIT2**

I have tested it with:

```
ODT,ADDED,AGE,CDT,CO,SEX,VALUE,TIME,COMMENT
P3,111,Y6-8,ACT,FG,F,1297,2011,cd
P4,222,Y3-3,EMP,FG,M,6940,2011,bd
P1,333,Y7-9,GRT,FG,F,0,2011,c
```

As input file and the output was:

```
ODT AGE CDT CO  SEX TIME    NUMB    STRING_COM  STRING_STATUS
P3  Y6-8    ACT FG  F   2011    1297        cd
P4  Y3-3    EMP FG  M   2011    6940        bd
P1  Y7-9    GRT FG  F   2011    0   c
```

Visually `bd` and `cd` are under `STRING_COM` column, the reason is that the header is longer than a tab size which is normally eight characters. The output is tab separated, it is possible to print two tabs to make these appear under `STRING_STATUS` but it might causes some issues if the output is intended to be used by another program, because it makes an empty field. If you need it only for printing you can change the line number 12 to this:

```
NR==1?"STRING_COM"OFS"STRING_STATUS":($a["COMMENT"]!="c"?""OFS""OFS$a["COMMENT"]:$a["COMMENT"]);
```

the output will be:

```
ODT AGE CDT CO  SEX TIME    NUMB    STRING_COM  STRING_STATUS
P3  Y6-8    ACT FG  F   2011    1297            cd
P4  Y3-3    EMP FG  M   2011    6940            bd
P1  Y7-9    GRT FG  F   2011    0   c
```

Comment: ok. I got it but how can I communicate further issues? is it ok here? or should I answer to my own question?

Comment: ok. how can I put the condition of having the length($a) ==1 together with $a["COMMENT"]!="c"? I mean what is the correct syntax in this case? do you advice this solution?

Comment: yes. perfect! it is working fine. I have tested in excel and the result is as expected

Comment: how it would be better to do the implementation? I have added in my main post some new functionalities. is it ok to put if statements after ($a["COMMENT"]!="c"...unfortunately I'm getting only errors...

Comment: In general no, it is a condition checked by `?:` operator.

Comment: I have put if statements between $a["COMMENT"]!="c"? { if $a["COMMENT"] ="u" && $a["VALUE"]=":" }""OFS....but it doesn't work. I believe a for is needed..but I don't know how

Comment: I have done some more tests and if the COMMENT is last column all the characters that are inside "c", "cd" or any other are associated to STRING_STATUS...so it seems that something is wrong. could you pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

I used Ashkan's answer as a starting point, and came up with the script below. However, these two points do not make sense in the context of a CSV file, unless the VALUE is surrounded by quotes (or something). Please clarify.

> 1. if the VALUE is "14,38" and COMMENT "d" then NUMB is "1438" and STRING(both) is null
> 2. if the VALUE is "14,38" and COMMENT "du" then NUMB is "1438" and STRING_STATUS is "u"

Awk script:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","; OFS="\t";
    a["ODT"]=1;a["AGE"]=1;a["CDT"]=1;a["CO"]=1;
    a["SEX"]=1;a["TIME"]=1;a["VALUE"]=1;a["COMMENT"]=1;
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in a) a[$i]=i;
    }
    print "ODT","AGE","CDT","CO","SEX","TIME","NUMB","STRING_COM","STRING_STATUS"
}
NR!=1{
    split($0,line,/,/);
    value = line[a["VALUE"]];
    comment = line[a["COMMENT"]];
    string_com="";
    string_status="";
    if (value==":") {
        value="";
        if (comment=="c") string_com = "c";
        if (comment=="u") string_status = "u";
        if (comment=="cd") string_com = "c";
        if (comment=="bc") {
            string_com = "c";
            string_status = "b";
        }
    }
    else {
        if (comment=="c")
            string_com = "c";
        else if (comment=="d") {
            # convert value
            string_com = "";
            string_status = "";
        }
        else if (comment=="du") {
            # convert value
            string_status = "";
        }
        else
            string_status = comment;
    }
    print line[a["ODT"]],
        line[a["AGE"]],
        line[a["CDT"]],
        line[a["CO"]],
        line[a["SEX"]],
        line[a["TIME"]],
        value,
        string_com,
        string_status
}
```